# How can I feed (Fortinet FortiGate 40F) Firewall log data to LimaCharlie without using a collector server that runs a LimaCharlie Adapter

Tags: firewall

[image]

I want to foward firewall logs from my Fortinet FortiGate 40F Firewall to [LimaCharlie](https://limacharlie.io/) without using a collector server (VM) in Azure that runs [LimaCharlie Adapter](https://docs.limacharlie.io/docs/telemetry-adapters).

How can this be done?